# Getting type error:can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'function'

Tags: python

I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\lab10.py", line 66, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\lab10.py", line 55, in main
    volumeRectangle=VR(length,width,height)
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\lab10.py", line 20, in VR
    volume=length*width*height
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'function'
```

Code

```
import math

def AC(radius):
    area = math.pi * radius ** 2
    return area

def AR(length,width):
    area=length*width
    return area

def VC(radius,height):
    volume=math.pi*radius*radius*height
    return volume

def VR(length,width,height):
    volume=length*width*height
    return volume

# WRITE ALL THE OTHER FUNCTIONS 

def main():

inFile = open("lab10.input","r")

# get calculation type, but wait on dimension(s)
type = (inFile.readline()).strip()

while (type != "###"): 
    if (type == "AC"):
        radius = eval(inFile.readline())
        circleArea = AC(radius)
        print(format("Area of a Circle","30s"),format(circleArea,"15.2f"))
    if (type=='AR'):
        length=eval(inFile.readline())
        width=eval(inFile.readline())
        rsArea=ARR(length,width)
        print(format("Area of a Rectangle or Square",'30s'),format(rsArea,'15.2f'))
    if (type=='VC'):
        radius=eval(inFile.readline())
        height=eval(inFile.readline())
        volumeCylinder=VC(radius,height)
        print(format("Volume of a Cylinder",'30s'),format(volumeCylinder,'15.2f'))
    if (type=='VR'):
        length=eval(inFile.readline())
        width=eval(inFile.readline())
        height=eval(inFile.readline())
        volumeRectangle=VR(length,width,height)
        print(format("Volume of a Rectangle",'30s'),format(volumeRectangle,'15.2f'))

    # do the processing for all other types of calculations 



    # get calculation type, but wait on dimension(s)
    type = (inFile.readline()).strip()

main()
```

This is what the input file looks like.  INPUT FILE

```
AC
7.5
SAC
4
VR
2, 3, 4.1
AR
13, 3.25
SAS

24
###
0
```

Comment: What does your input file look like?

Comment: You have overloaded the built-in `type`. This might have several side effects. You should rename the variable.

Comment: just edited it in, after each space there's a new line, the formattting just messed up

Comment: Ok well i've fixed the variable and it is now giving me this error                 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\lab10.py", line 66, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\lab10.py", line 39, in main
    circleArea = AC(radius)
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\lab10.py", line 8, in AC
    area = math.pi * radius * radius
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
>>>

Comment: Your code treats each parameter as if it were on a separate line in the file. This is not the case. They are all on the same line.

Comment: can you explain what you mean bythat

Comment: Sure check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seem to work. Like Paul said inputs in the same lines were getting messed up.

```
while (type != "###"):
    if (type == "AC"):
        radius = eval(inFile.readline())
        circleArea = AC(radius)
        print(format("Area of a Circle","30s"),format(circleArea,"15.2f"))
    if (type=='AR'):
        length, width=eval(inFile.readline().strip())
        rsArea=AR(length,width)
        print(format("Area of a Rectangle or Square",'30s'),format(rsArea,'15.2f'))
    if (type=='VC'):
        radius, height=eval(inFile.readline().strip())
        volumeCylinder=VC(radius,height)
        print(format("Volume of a Cylinder",'30s'),format(volumeCylinder,'15.2f'))
    if (type=='VR'):
        length, width, height =eval(inFile.readline().strip())
        volumeRectangle=VR(length,width,height)
        print(format("Volume of a Rectangle",'30s'),format(volumeRectangle,'15.2f'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running into issues when you hit the `VR` command. This is because it has multiple input parameters. You 'got away with it' in the first command (`AC`) as it has only a single parameter and `eval` turned it into a single `float` value.

For `VR` there are 3 parameters and you are trying to set each of these parameters by reading a line in the file (that's 3 lines read). Now all your parameters are actually together on single line. So if you thought you were reading the parameters

```
12, 3, 4.1
```

You are not you are reading

```
2, 3, 4.1
AR
13, 3.25
```

When you `eval` these you get tuples for the 1st and 3rd lines and since `AR` is a function you defined, `eval('AR')` returns you that function (which makes sense of the exception error message you received). This is one of the hazards of using `eval`, it can lead to unexpected results.

So your VR call looks like

```
VR((2, 3, 4.1), AR, (13, 3.25))
```

Which is doubtless not what you expected.

Two ways you could resolve it. I've abbreviated your code for clarity. You'd obviously need to replicate in the other commands.

Stick with the `tuples` and [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) (use that instead of `eval`).

```
import math
from ast import literal_eval

def VR(length,width,height):
    return length * width * height

def main():

    with open("lab10.input","r") as inFile:
        acttype = (inFile.readline()).strip()

        while (acttype != "###"): 
            if (acttype=='VR'):
                params = literal_eval(inFile.readline())
                volumeRectangle = VR(*params)
                print(format("Volume of a Rectangle",'30s'),format(volumeRectangle,'15.2f'))

            acttype = (inFile.readline()).strip()

main()
```

or avoid the `eval` by splitting the line on `,`.

```
import math

def VR(length,width,height):
    return length * width * height

def main():

    with open("lab10.input","r") as inFile:
        acttype = (inFile.readline()).strip()

        while (acttype != "###"): 
            if (acttype=='VR'):
                params = map(float, inFile.readline().split(','))
                volumeRectangle = VR(*params)
                print(format("Volume of a Rectangle",'30s'),format(volumeRectangle,'15.2f'))

            acttype = (inFile.readline()).strip()

main()
```